# how to modify string with special characters to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, foreach

I have a string with special characters, I have to modify to array of object using javascript

so in a string, always before underscore considered as `name`

and after underscore is considered as `type`

- if semicolon is present, then can be two diff objects

tried

```
var arr = str2.split(';');
var result = arr.find( e => {
  e.split(/[_,]/);
}).map(i => ({
  name: i[0],
  type: i.shift()
}));
```

```
var str1 = "xyz_dell,asus";
var str2 = "abc_new;red_old;zen_sg,my"

Expected Output for str1

[
  {name: xyz, type: dell,asus}
]

Expected Output for str2

[
  {name: abc, type: new},
  {name: red, type: old},
  {name: zen, type: sg, my}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` first on `;` and use flatMap and use `split` on `_`

```js
const process = (str) =>
  str.split(";").flatMap((item) => {
    const [name, type] = item.split("_");
    return { name, type };
  });

var str1 = "xyz_dell,asus";
var str2 = "abc_new;red_old;zen_sg,my";

console.log(process(str1));
console.log(process(str2));
```